# I am trying to read an array coming from python(database mongodb), and read it in a context menu submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

So, I am trying to read the array coming from python and python is calling mongodb. As I am trying to read the array, I am getting each character from the array. Like the code is reading the array as a string.

I have tried reading this code in various ways but always getting stuck. First, I am reading the value and putting it in a const variable. Then I am creating a for loop to loop through the array and display each item like '1 - client 1'...

```
var displayClient = [];
const clients = document.getElementById("clients").value;
var clients_array = clients;
console.log(clients);

var itemDisp = [];
var arrayLength = clients_array.length;

//looping through the objects inside the object
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var client = clients_array[i].toString().split(',');
    displayClient.push(client[0] + ' - ' + client[1]);
    itemDisp.push({ label: displayClient[i]});  
}

//calling to diplay in the context menu
return { 
    "AddClient" : {
    label: "Add Client",                        
    "submenu": itemDisp, 
    disabled: false
}

//the array which I am trying to read
[['1', 'client 1'], ['2', 'client 2']]
```

the expected result is, to display something like; 1 - client 1... While the actual result is; [ - undefined, [ - undefined, ' - undefined...

Comment: what does your `clients_array` variable contain? I'm pretty sure it's not an array.

Comment: I did a console.log on clients_array, and it gave me the exact result like there is in the code sample, meaning; [['1', 'client 1'], ['2', 'client 2']]

Comment: `const clients = document.getElementById("clients").value;` can't be an array. It must be a string.

Comment: console.log(clients_array) and tell us the result.

Comment: As I have already said, console.log(clients_array) gave me: [['1', 'client 1'], ['2', 'client 2']]

Comment: can someone tell me how should I properly read an array using document.getElementById?

Comment: @TahaPaksu you are right this is not getting an array

Comment: document.getElementById("clients").value.split(yourseparator)

Comment: @LajosArpad I tried your example but I am getting: [['1' - undefined, 'client 1'] - undefined,...

Comment: What value do you attempt to convert into array? What did you chose as value for yourseparator?

Comment: Moreover, in the console.log(clients_array) I have like: ["[['1'", " 'client 1']", " ['2'", " 'client 2']"

Comment: I am using split(',')

Comment: In clients_array you already have the result of the attempt. I would like to know what is your input. Without that it is very difficult to help you.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by input?

Comment: I guess that the problem is that I have a 2d array while the code is putting my value into a 1d array

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return { 
   "AddClient" : {
     label: "Add Client",                        
     "submenu": itemDisp, 
     disabled: false
  }
}
```

I make this and work:

```
var displayClient = [];
const clients = [['1', 'client 1'], ['2', 'client 2']];
var clients_array = clients;
console.log(clients);

var itemDisp = [];
var arrayLength = clients_array.length;

//looping through the objects inside the object
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  var client = clients_array[i].toString().split(',');
  displayClient.push(client[0] + ' - ' + client[1]);
  itemDisp.push({ label: displayClient[i]});  
}

//calling to diplay in the context menu
let test = { 
  "AddClient" : {
    label: "Add Client",                        
    "submenu": itemDisp, 
    disabled: false
  }
}

console.log(test);
console.log(itemDisp);
```

Comment: this is not the way that I should do it :/ as I am reading the array from mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand your code but I might understood your problem. This code can help you get the desired output :-

`

```
var itemDisp = [];
const clients = document.getElementById("clients").value;
try{
    // This line will parse your array string into JS array object
    var clientsArray = JSON.parse(clients.replace(/'/g,"\""));

    for(var internalArray of clientsArray){
        itemDisp.push({label : internalArray.join(" - ")});
    }
}catch(e){
    console.error("String provided is not a valid array string");
}

console.log(itemDisp);
```

`